# None of the tools in the GIMP 2.8 toolbox are functional

Tags: gimp

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a 64bit machine. I recently upgraded to Gimp 2.8 with no problems. All user interface items appear to work - except - none of the tools in the toolbox are functional. Attempts to crop, move, brush, etc. change the cursor but perform no action.  I went to the .gimp-2.8 file (in home) and found all files to be empty.

I then went to /usr/share/gimp and found files under gimp 2.0 and tried copying them to the .gimp-2.8 file but with no luck. All file/folder paths listed in preferences are correct, and I have had no luck finding any info at Gimp HQ or using Google.

Can you help me find my missing tools, I have no idea if they were misfiled or simply not installed. All the gimp-2.8 files are there in the Home folder but they are 0 files......

Answer (score 0):

I think the GIMP2.8 should be in /usr/share/gimp not the other way around. Try moving your install there, instead of moving your installed files to your 2.8 that's in your home dir.

Comment: @edm,  I installed by software center through the 'kegel' ppa. Had no problems with the instalation, no warnings, nothing. Also everything works except the tolls in the toolbox - even the menu items work.

Comment: @Eliah, I tried moving to user/share and it didn't help.

Comment: it is `/usr/share`(the root folder) not `user/share`

Comment: Correction: I meant /usr/share/gimp.